# Html added by jQuery .html() is not visible to javascript functions

Tags: jquery

Every couple of seconds on the server I generate a chunk of html, which I display in UI by using jQuery method .html().

```
    $('#contentContainer').html(JSON.parse(htmlString));
```

Injected html is correctly displayed.

However, there are also some javascript functions, which manipulate this html code.
For example, one is connected to the div element:

```
$("#startStop").click(function () { ..});
```

Another to bootstrap tooltip:

```
    $(function () {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
        $(".errorTip").tooltip();
    });
```

The problem is that they no longer work when I populate the div element with the html from the server.

I can see that the elements are created with correct ids:

```
    <div id="startStop" data-toggle="button" class="sbClickable btn active">
    ....
    </div>
```

The only difference, is that when I open the source code in chrome, the generated html is missing there.

Here are the steps, how I load code to the page:

1. page.chtml file is loaded
2. in the page.chtml there is an empty div

   ```
   <div id="contentContainer">
   </div>
   ```
3. then in page.chtml I call a method to populate the container. The method is located in external .js file

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       einzelaktion.populateHtml();
   </script>
   ```
4. in populateHtml I make an ajax request to the server. When data is retrieved I empty the div and populate it with the new data:

   ```
   $('#contentContainer div').empty();
   $('#contentContainer').html(JSON.parse(htmlString));
   ```
5. Methods, with which I have problems located in the  same external .js file.

I tried moving method, which populates the container, to page.chtml, but it didn't help.

I also tried to create container elements when page is loaded in a straightforward manner, so they are created together with other elements for page.chtml and they are visible in the page source. In this case, everything works correctly till I make a first call to server and replace the html for the div.

I googled similar problems, but didn't find anything close to my issue..

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$("#startStop").click(function () { ..});
```

to

```
$("#contentContainer").on('click', '#startStop', function () { ..});
```

This way, the elements having id `startStop` and being created after you call the binding function will receive the click event.

Comment: You might want to replace '#startStop' with a class selector like '.sbClickable.btn.active'. `elements having id startStop` sounds wrong since an id should be unique. But Anelook only mentions one example for an element with a correct id so it should be okay. You could change your fiddle if it gets accepted though.

Comment: @junior I assume there is no duplication of the #startStop element as the whole #contentContainer content is replaced.

Comment: Works perfectly! And for the tooltip - I call the function tooltip() every time I update the container. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add HTML to the DOM after it is loaded already, you must use jQuery's on() function to create a bind...

For instance, 
`$(".newDiv").on('click', function() { alert('clicked dynamic HTML!')});`